# Cannot vote on answer unless edited because it is locked

Tags: support, answers, voting

I tried to vote on the other [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/240600/access-to-cd-dvd-drive-is-denied-through-windows-7-explorer-permission-problem/248332#248332) to my [question](https://superuser.com/questions/240600/access-to-cd-dvd-drive-is-denied-through-windows-7-explorer-permission-problem/), but it says I can’t unless it is edited because my “vote” from 45 minutes ago is locked. The [only vote on that answer](https://superuser.com/posts/240600/timeline) was from well over a week ago and neither arrow next to the answer is highlighted.

Answer (score 5):

You have a 5 minute window to cast and uncast votes; after the first vote is cast, the clock starts ticking.

Regardless of the final state, the clock starts ticking the second you click a vote arrow.

This is to prevent many kinds of vote undo exploits.

Answer (score 3):

I see only 1 upvote on harrymc's answer from the timeline. This plus you indicate that you're getting a message about vote being locked makes me believe this might have happened:

- Clicked on the upvote
- (Accidentally?) clicked on the upvote again, hence "cancelling" it. The system still sees it as a vote - after all you did vote on it. The vote is now locked.

I can simulate the same -

Voted for your answer

[image]

Now cancelled my vote. There's no sign of the upvote and it's locked in till the post gets edited.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Sometimes the mouse and/or keyboard perform phantom clicks/keypresses. It happens when a wireless device has a bad RF-connection/low battery, or when the metal contacts on micro-switches have accumulated a patina, preventing a good electrical connection. I’ve had them now and then in the past year, so that may have been it (or maybe I just noticed or thought of something and changed my mind right after clicking it).